# How do I create a smart object grid?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, cs6, smartobject, layout

I'm using Photoshop CS6. I want to create a grid layout template (something like this: https://www.etsy.com/uk/listing/683684779/collage-template-photoshop-square). I want the area for the content to be smart objects. How do I do that?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You can do that by creating the grid and transforming it to a smart object. What exactly you’re struggling with?

Answer (score 0):

1. Make a simple grid from shapes.
2. Right click each shape in the layers panel, and choose Convert to Smart Object. Repeat for each shape.
3. Save your blank template.

[image]

4. To use the template, open it, and double click on a smart object in the layers panel to open it
5. Copy and paste/place an image, then position and scale it image to fit the shape or overlap it slightly, close and save the smart object. Repeat for all images.

[image]

Comment: THANK YOU!!!!!!